# Delete old records from table which does not have any timestamp or date column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres database which has a lot of records (30,00,000+).

I want to delete all records which are older than an year but I see that there is no timestamp or date column in this table.

How can I delete the old records in this case? (first I want to get the count of records which are older than 1 year)

Also, will deleting huge number of records in a single SQL query cause performance issues while the deletion is in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A row in a PostgreSQL table has no age unless you explicitly store it with the data, so there is no way to do that. You have to use a condition based on the data.

Deleting many data can take a long time, even if all [foreign keys are indexed](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/). The king's way to speedy mass deletions is table partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

As @laurenze_albe has said, there is no way to get the age of a row of data. Probably, you'll end up deleting based on some kind of id field. If you have the time, you could monitor how many records are added during a week, and then make a guess for the number of records in a year.

If you get max(id) from today and then max(id) a week from now, you could subtract the difference and multiply by 52.